# IntentSevice started by JobService is destroyed immediately. How can I prevent this?

Tags: android, service

I'm doing the app that should be crash safe. Meaning that it should start again even if something went wrong and crash happened.

Implementing this I do the following:

I have working service `MyIntentService` that starts working thread and does the job.

Also I schedule `JobService` that checks if the working thread is alive. If not - `JobService` sends `Intent` to the working service.

Everything works perfectly except one thing: when working thread crashes and `JobService` call `startService()`, `onCreate()` of working service 
is called and than `onDestroy()` is called immediately. Even if I make `Notification` and call `startForeground()` for working service.

How can I change situation to make working service work after restart?

Here is my **scheduler**:

```
public class CheckAliveJService extends JobService {

    private static final String TAG = CheckAliveJService.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final int JOB_SCHEDULE_ID = 1;

    public CheckAliveJService() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {

        Log.i(TAG, "onStartJob()");


        startService(new Intent(this, TransactionService.class)
                            .setAction(TransactionService.ACTION_WAKEUP));

        jobFinished(jobParameters, true);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        return false;
    }

    public static void scheduleService(Context context, long millisecPeriod){

        Log.i(TAG, "scheduleService()");

        if(millisecPeriod <= 0){
            return;
        }

        JobInfo.Builder builder =
                new JobInfo.Builder(JOB_SCHEDULE_ID,
                    new ComponentName(context, CheckAliveJService.class))
                    .setPeriodic(millisecPeriod)
                    .setPersisted(true);

        JobScheduler tm = (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
        tm.schedule(builder.build());
    }

    public static void unscheduleService(Context context){
        Log.i(TAG, "unscheduleService()");

        JobScheduler tm = (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
        tm.cancel(JOB_SCHEDULE_ID);

    }
}
```

Here is **working service**

```
public class MyIntentService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = MyIntentService.class.getSimpleName();


 @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MyIntentService.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

        builder.setContentTitle("setContentTitle")
                .setContentText("let's dance")
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setTicker("setTicker");

        startForeground(2208, builder.build());

        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - mLastThreadCall >= WAKEUP_TIMEOUT) {
            startWorkingThread();
        }       
    }

    @Override
        public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    }       

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy()");  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> onCreate() of working service is called and than onDestroy() is called immediately.

It does that all the time. That is because you chose to extend `IntentService`. An `IntentService` lives long enough for `onHandleIntent()` to complete its work. After that, if no more work is pending, the `IntentService` calls `stopSelf()` and the service is destroyed.

> How can I change situation to make working service work after restart?

Extend `Service` instead of `IntentService`, moving your code from `onHandleIntent()` into `onStartCommand()`.